# Java Maven Cucumber how to correctly rerun tests from the commandline?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

Hi i'm using i'm currently using Cucumber version 6.8.1 and i'm trying to figure out how to solve rerunning of failed tests. I've hacked together my own solution but it feels incorrect. In order for

```
maven clean install
```

to detect the test runners i appended Test to their names:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/cucumber", "rerun:target/rerun.txt" })
public class CucumberRunnerTest {

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "@target/rerun.txt",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
public class RerunningTest {

}
```

Now this works but it seems a bit hacky. since commands like

```
    mvn clean install -Dcucumber.glue="cucumber" \                            
   -Dcucumber.plugin="de.monochromata.cucumber.report.PrettyReports:target/cucumber" \
   -Dcucumber.plugin="rerun:target/rerun.txt"
```

should work, but don't work. The build is successful but no tests run. It's like Dcucumber is being ignored by maven. However, after appending "Test" to the runners and then running the command above uses both runners since they're treated as Tests which feels wrong.

So my question is how can i make this work correctly with Dcucumber?

Comment: Couldn't you use a a single custom maven profile for this? then you could just run `mvn clean install -DcukeTests`

Comment: @Lino i'm a huge maven noob :D could you point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't name your test class `*Test` then Surefire won't recognize it. Naming convention wise, try using `RunCucumberTest` instead. It isn't too ugly.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

> Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests
> Inclusions
>
> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> ```
>    "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
>    "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
>    "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
>    "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
> ```
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions, then configure Surefire Plugin and specify the tests you want to include.